# Upgrade Umbraco v7 to v8 - Migrating obsolete datatypes

Tags: web, umbraco, umbraco7, updating, umbraco8

I try to upgrade my website from V7 to V8 (then hopefully V9, V10, etc.)

As a first step before I even begin with the actual upgrade process, I try to migrate the obsolete datatypes.

I was reading few articles / answers here and in other places and I try to figure out how to do it manually.

I understand that I can't only change in the back office but also in the database. I was reading some people created scripts but I'm little hesitant to run others scripts on my database, so I was thinking to do it manually .

My question - where in the database I need to make the changes after I change in the Backoffice and what do I need to change?

Does the changes I need to perform are only:

Umbraco.MultipleMediaPicker -> new editor: Umbraco.MediaPicker2

Umbraco.MediaPicker -> new editor: Umbraco.MediaPicker2

Umbraco.ContentPickerAlias -> new editor: Umbraco.ContentPicker2 etc. ?

It means, do I need to find in the DB for example Umbraco.MultipleMediaPicker and rename to Umbraco.MediaPicker2 ?

Please advise.

Thanks.

Bellow a screenshot of my db:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Updating to use the new datatypes is achieved using migrations.

https://www.proworks.com/blog/archive/how-to-upgrade-umbraco-version-7-to-version-8/ - this is a very useful blog post that highlights everything you should need to upgrade from v7 to v8.

https://bitbucket.org/proworks/proworks.umbraco8.migrations/src/master/ - this repo has multiple examples of migrations from the old obsolete datatypes to the new ones. You should be able to add a series of migrations for the datatypes you are interested in/are currently using.

There is far too much code to copy, hence the links. Hopefully these will be helpful.

**Important - I would take a backup of your database prior to running any migrations**